# Is it possible to read a web.configuration file and add some tags in another web.config file?

Tags: c#, .net

Let us consider a web.config file deployed from website....

let us take another project say console application or some class file then is it possible to read that web.configuration file and add some tags in that web.config file

i just want to add these lines in to it

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="sample" type="sample.class" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Waiting for your valuable comments

Comment: yes... you can read the file and look for anything inside `<*>*</*>`, finding specific tags would be more challenging.

Comment: you haven't provided a context as to why you need this. SO isn't a discussion board. that is what StackMetaData is for

Comment: can you give me some example code which will help me to proceed @LyubenTodorov

Comment: @Gowthammanju You need to parse through the file and look for specific tags, how you will find the tags is upto you.

Here is code to parse through the html file.

`var webConfigFile = new HtmlDocument(); //Html because (i hope) you know that web.config is in xhtml 
doc.Load(webConfigFile); 
var scripts = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div"); // finds the data between <div></div> tags`

Comment: Thanks for acceptance, also vote up to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** Read this [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20016/Reading-and-Writing-app-config-or-web-config-Setti) and download source code, it may help you to read/write new section in config files.

To read the `AppSettings` from the `Web.Config` file you can use the ConfigurationSettings or ConfigurationManager Class.

It works like the following

```
string connectionInfo = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionInfo"];
```

ConnectionInfo is in the Web.config file under the AppSettings like

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ConnectionInfo" value="server=(local);database=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
</appSettings>
```

and to write in the web.config AppSettings section.. Let's say you have a key 'SiteName' in your appsettings section of your config file... you can update it like that..

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");  
config.AppSettings.Settings["SiteName"].Value = "New Site Name Value";  
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);  
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: no i need to add <system.webserver> tag to existing web.config file

Comment: The web.config file only works natively in a web project. The ConfigurationManager of a console app (et al) would only read its relevant app.config. It's not impossible to read the web.config, but it would require much more than you've put here.

Comment: but through xmlreader we can view it and make changes as we want @JoelEtherton

Comment: @Gowthammanju: if it is not working for you, than look for xmlreader/ xmlwriter classes or other xml doc classes

Comment: @Gowthammanju: Absolutely, but at the time of my comment, none of those updates were there.

Comment: @talha its not wrking can u provide me some samples through xmlreader/ xmlwriter classes

Comment: @Gowthammanju: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20016/Reading-and-Writing-app-config-or-web-config-Setti